# How can I put an AngularJS page inside a crm-popup modal window?

Tags: developer, angular

If I add `class="crm-popup"` to an internal hyperlink in CiviCRM, I can make CiviCRM open the target page inside a modal dialog. Cool!

But if the target page is an *AngularJS page* (e.g. `/civicrm/a/#/mailing/1`, or `/civicrm/a/#/status`), then this technique doesn't seem to work. I can open the link in a new new tab, but when I click to open the modal dialog I see the following:

1. modal dialog opens
2. inside it I see a large spinning CiviCRM icon which tells me AngularJS is loading
3. I see the text `Unknown path` inside the modal dialog.

For my extension, I'd actually like to use a custom AngularJS page on top of a custom base base, and I have this working. But when I try to load my page inside a `crm-popup` I get the same failure as noted above, except on step 3 I don't see `Unknown path`, and I do see the following console error message:

`TypeError: newUrl.split(...)[1] is undefined[Learn More]  crm.ajax.js:167:14`

I'd love to know if there's a way I can adjust my AngularJS page, my base page, or my popup link to get the AngularJS page to load inside the modal dialog.